# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {login, id, nod etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Objects are not valid as a React child**

(found: object with keys `{login, id, node_id, avatar_url, gravatar_id, url, html_url, followers_url, following_url, gists_url, starred_url, subscriptions_url, organizations_url, repos_url, events_url, received_events_url, type, site_admin}`).

If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.(these is the full error ).

I have tried to `concat` and used `array.push` and even es6 spread to add these array response into empty array state

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        nicknameValue: '',
        nicknameSuggestions: [],
        users: []
    };
}

componentWillMount() {

    axios.get('https://api.github.com/users')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);

            const persons = response.data;
            console.log(persons);
            this.setState({
                users: this.state.users.concat([...persons])
            })
            console.log(this.state.users);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

expecting users array

Comment: What are you doing within your `render` method?

Comment: What do console logs say? Is everything an array as predicted?

Comment: `persons` variable is valid?

Comment: i am trying to set "users" array with the response array

Comment: `const persons = response.data;` So you are saying that response.data is an array.  You should check that.

Comment: I tried your code and I could find no issue.

https://repl.it/@pegasus1982/FinancialQuerulousLesson

So what you want exactly?

Comment: am unable to do the setState({users: this.state.users.concat([...persons])})

Comment: thanks its working after checking your code @Jin

Comment: `Objects are not valid as a React child` in your render method you are likely doing something like `this.state.users.map(x => <tag>{x}</tag>)`. If that array is strings that's fine, but if it is an object then: `Objects are not valid as a React child` Please post your render method.

Answer (score 1):

Please reference my code.

[repl.it/@pegasus1982/FinancialQuerulousLesson](https://repl.it/@pegasus1982/FinancialQuerulousLesson)

I checked your code